# Debugging iPad when in sleep/locked state

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

Has anyone been able to debug via Xcode when the iPad is in sleep or locked state?  I know I can run UIAutomation sleepForDuration() but obviously you cannot debug in Xcode while in instruments?

I'm having a problem with network connectivity when the iPad locks and then awakens and need to find a way to debug it.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

yes the debugger still work when your device is slept / locked, given that you run the app with Xcode.